# See hide src iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need see src.
Code is:

```
<iframe
  name="Player"
  ""=""
  src="./player3/serverf5hlb.php?vid=LGDJSTCZCKSNYDR&amp;ads=homeingles.fun"
  scrolling="no"
  allowfullscreen=""
  width="100%" height="100%"
  frameborder="0"
></iframe>
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, I invite you to take the site tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Iframe from an active website, you should just be able to view page source and click on the file path to view the php file in the src parameter. Assuming that is what you are looking for. I would need more context to assist you